# Custom command to represent $L_1$ metric distance that works both inside and outside math mode

Tags: macros

I'm trying to write to define `\ds(a,b)` so that it results in `$||a - b||_1$`. This should also work inside a math environment e.g. as part of an inequality statement, but I should be able to use it in the body of the text as `\ds(a,b)` without enclosing it in $$.

So far, I've managed this, browsing other similar questions in Tex.SE:

```
\def\ds#1{\innerds(#1)}
\def\innerds(#1,#2) {\ensuremath{||#1 - #2||_1}\xspace}
```

This works to a certain extent - I can write `\ds(a,b)` as part of text, but for some reason, I get the following error when I use it inside math mode:

```
Runaway argument?
c||_1\xspace \] \end {document} 
! File ended while scanning use of \innerds.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> mwe_macro.tex

! Emergency stop.
<*> mwe_macro.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

MWE (that I've tried) is given below:

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xspace}

\def\ds#1{\innerds(#1)}
\def\innerds(#1,#2) {\ensuremath{||#1 - #2||_1}\xspace}

\begin{document}
Outside math mode: \ds(a,b)
Inside math mode: $\ds(a,b)$
Inside displaymath:
\[ \ds(a,b) + \ds(b,c) \geq \ds(a,c) \]
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: Combining the two answers and the comments below, this is what I've adopted which works pretty fine for my intents:

```
  \def\ds(#1,#2){\innerds{#1}{#2}}
  \def\innerds#1#2{\ensuremath{\lVert #1 - #2\rVert}}
```

(Note that I've dropped the subscript 1 - I need it only once when I define the notion of the distance being used, hence I've moved it out of the macro).

Comment: What's bad in `$\ds(a,b)$`? It's math, after all, so it is *never* in text. In any case, you don't need `\xspace`.

Comment: @egreg - I don't want to have to type $$ every time i use the notation - I've used ensuremath before to do that, so I know its doable (or should be doable at least!)

Comment: No! `\lvert\lvert` is wrong! It's simply `\lVert`.

Comment: ensuremath is generally not a good idea. TeX has a clear distinction between math mode and non math mode, compare `\^` (text accent) `\hat` (math accent) making commands work in either is possible but complicates the language and the code and doesn't make the document any clearer.

Comment: **Please do not do that.** Sincerely, your Copy Editor.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for pointing that out - I didn't know that it existed! Btw, the output does look exactly the same, so I'm curious - other than the simpler expression, where would the output be wrong if I use 2 lverts instead of lVert?

Comment: @tohecz - Did u mean usage of xpace, ensuremath or double lverts (all but one is corrected now btw) ?

Comment: @TCSGrad Well, if I were to copy-edit your work, I would change `||` into `\|` probably, get rid of `xspace` and try to figure out a regex to separate text-mode usage of the macro from the math-mode one, calling you names ;)

Comment: @tochecz: According to @egreg, `\lvert` is preferable to `\|` - but you seem to prefer the latter! I'm pretty confused as to what is the best usage in general! :) I've gotten rid of \xspace, but I certainly give up for trying to develop a regex! Maybe if you can show me an example where `ensuremath` fails spectacularly in the generated pdf, I'd consider not using it in a macro in future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, when you use `\ds(a,b)` the `\ds` macro just picks up `(` as its argument. You need something like this.

```
\def\ds(#1,#2){\innerds{#1}{#2}}
\def\innerds#1#2{\ensuremath{||#1 - #2||_1}\xspace}
```

Comment: What's `\xspace` supposed to do? Macros with arguments *never* need `\xspace`. And why two macros when one is sufficient? Why `||` which is the wrong way to obtain two bars?

Comment: @egreg --- no idea; I just fixed the problem that caused to OP's construction to fail.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `\ds` is wrong. If you want a syntax like

```
\ds(a,b)
```

then you should simply do

```
\def\ds(#1,#2){\ensuremath{\|#1-#2\|_1}}
```

(note `\|` and not `||`). There's no need for `\xspace`, because spaces are not ignored after `)`.

However, I don't see why using `\ensuremath` either. I find it much clearer if math is *always* treated as math. There's not much gain in typing

```
The distance \ds(a,b) is less than $1$
```

instead of

```
The distance $\ds(a,b)$ is less than $1$
```

So I'd much prefer

```
\def\ds(#1,#2){\|#1-#2\|_1}
```

With `amsmath` you can improve it as

```
\def\ds(#1,#2){\lVert #1-#2\rVert_1}
```

Comment: @TCSGrad You may be fond of `\xspace`, but ***really*** it does ***nothing*** where you place it (I'm referring to the accepted answer). To be more precise: it can only cause harm.

Comment: OK, I've removed it - it got there as an artifact of a previous `newcommand` that I was modifying to get this macro to work, which did need it. But other than that, I would *really* prefer to remove the requirement of $$ each time I type it, which is the primary reason I accepted the other answer!

Comment: @TCSGrad no macro _needs_ `\xspace` (it really wasn't that good an idea to make that package:-)